# How to transfer Django's messages to Angular app

Tags: python, django, angular

I am building Django 2.2 +Node + Angular 8 app. Django is used to run a couple of simple scrapers when user clicks on Search btn. I want to make user notified that the scraping process started successfully (if it is the fact) and that the scraping is finished, or that some errors occurred. Some intermediate statuses are also desirable, but not mandatory. I thought about using django.contrib.messages, but not sure how to make my Angular app receive them. 
Can anybody advise me with that problem?

P.S.: not sure if it is important - I want to use Angular's snackbar to make user notified about scraping statuses.

Answer (score 2):

there is only one common way to push messages from Django to angular (from server -> to client), is to create a **web-socket**.

Check out this [tutorial](https://devarea.com/angular-and-django-websockets-communication/) to create a web-socket that initiate a connexion between Angular and Django, and *then* pushing random notificatons from Django to Angular and *finally* closing the websocket.

In your case :

- Open Web Socket when starting the task
- Sending notifications about the task (DJANGO -> NG)
- Sending Final Notification and Closing Web Socket

For other ideas checkout this medium: [Do you really need websockets ?](https://blog.stanko.io/do-you-really-need-websockets-343aed40aa9b)